# When last element of a loop is displayed, show another element outside of loop

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a php foreach loop with the following inside:

```
<div class="form-row">...</div>
```

This can create an unlimited amount of `form-row` divs. I have next/back buttons to only show one at a time so you can move forward and back through the rows.

Outside of that I have this button:

```
<button class="test"></button>
```

I want to do something like the following:

```
$('.form-row:last'){        
   $('button.test').show();
}
```

E.g When it's on the last element of the `form-row` div, I want it to show the button.

How can I do that?

If it was in the `form-row` loop then I would just use `$('button.test').last().show();` but as it's outside of that, I'm not sure what to do.

This is my full code:

```
                    <?php global $current_user;
                    get_currentuserinfo();
                    $user = $current_user->user_login; ?>
                    <form class="form" method="POST" action="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/training-insert.php">
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user; ?>" name="test-user" />
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo the_title(); ?>" name="test-name" />
                        <?php $counter = 1; if(get_field('step_by_step_training')): ?>
                        <?php while(the_repeater_field('step_by_step_training')): ?>    
                            <div class="form-row">
                              <h2 style="float:left;margin-left:7px;">
                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                              </h2>
                              <h2 style="float:right;"><?php echo $counter; ?> of <?php echo $total; ?></h2>
                              <div class="clear"></div>
                              <div id="module-area" style="margin-top:0px!IMPORTANT;">
                                <div id="modules-top"></div>
                                <div id="modules-repeat">
                                  <p class="training"><?php echo the_sub_field('introduction'); ?></p>
                                  <?php if(get_sub_field('training_images')): ?>
                                  <?php while(has_sub_field('training_images')): ?>
                                  <img class="training" src="<?php echo the_sub_field('image'); ?>" />
                                  <?php endwhile; ?>
                                  <?php endif; ?>
                                  <p class="training"><?php echo the_sub_field('conclusion'); ?></p>
                                  <div class="inner"></div>
                                  <button class="next"></button>
                                  <button class="end"></button>
                                  <div class="clear"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="margin-bottom:5px;" id="modules-bottom"></div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php $counter++; endwhile; ?> 
                        <?php endif; ?> 
                    </form>
                    <?php if (get_field('test') != "") { ?>
                        <form class="form" method="POST" action="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/training-insert-alt.php">
                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user; ?>" name="test-user" />
                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo the_title(); ?>" name="test-name" />
                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo the_field('test'); ?>" name="test-link" />
                            <button class="test"></button>
                        </form>
                    <?php } ?>

            <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {    

    // prepend a 'previous' button to all form-rows except the first
    $('<button>').addClass('previous').appendTo($('.inner').not(':first'));

    // hide all form-rows, but not the first one
    $('.form-row').not(':first').hide();

    // hide on last step
    $('button.next').last().hide();
    $('button.end').last().show();

if($('.form-row:last').is(':visible')) { 
   $('button.test').show();
} 

    // add the submit button to the last form-row
    // $('<input>').addClass('submit').prop('type', 'submit').val('My Dashboard').appendTo($('.form-row:last'));


    // handle the previous button, we need to use 'on' here as the
    // previous buttons don't exist in the dom at page load
    $('.form-row').on('click', 'button.previous', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('div.form-row').hide().prev('div.form-row').show();
    });

    $('button.next').click(function(e) {
        // prevent the next buttons from submitting the form
        e.preventDefault();
        // hide this form-row, and show the next one
        $(this).parents('div.form-row').hide().next('div.form-row').show();
    });       

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: maybe this? http://api.jquery.com/last/

Comment: @GoE The button is outside of the loop so using last doesn't seem to work with what I tried.

Comment: can you post your loop? then we can better help you

Comment: Why can't you do it with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using this:

```
$('.form-row').last().append($('button.test').show());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('.form-row:last').is(':visible')) { 
   $('button.test').show();
}
```

Wrap that in a function and call it everytime you show your next row. Or include it directly to the part where you show the next row:

```
$('button.next').click(function(e) {
    // prevent the next buttons from submitting the form
    e.preventDefault();
    // hide this form-row, and show the next one
    $(this).parents('div.form-row').hide().next('div.form-row').show();

    if($('.form-row:last').is(':visible')) 
       $('button.test').show();
});
```

And if you want to hide the button when you press the previous button:

```
$('.form-row').on('click', 'button.previous', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('div.form-row').hide().prev('div.form-row').show();
    $('button.test').hide();
});
```